$f$ is continuous nowhere but $|f|$ is continuous everywhere
I had already seen that there are many posts here reagarding this question.
If there exists a function $f : [0,1] \to\mathbb R$ which is discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$ then is $|f(x)|$
continuous at every point in $[0,1]$.
But I saw that everywhere people had assumed functions  but no one had actually given an answer whether this is generalised or not...
Does this statement work for every functions which satisfies the above statement or is it false?
Can anyone please provide a proof for this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you exactly mean by generalized? Could you write the 'generalized statement' in your question, so it can be verified to be true or false?

Generalized in the sense can it be called a theorem?? Is it valid for every discontinuous function at every point in the interval [0,1]?

So do you mean the statement: "If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$ then $|f(x)|$ is continuous at every point in $[0,1]$" right?

@RupertRybka yes

The statement says that there exists atleast one function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$ where $|f|$ is continuous at every point in $[0,1]$.
Take for example
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} x \in \mathbb Q \\
-1, & \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} x \notin \mathbb Q \\
\end{cases}$$
This function satisfies the conditions stated and therefore the statement is true. The statement doesn't say anything more than that.
On the other hand, the function
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} x \in \mathbb Q \\
0, & \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} x \notin \mathbb Q \\
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$ but $g(x)$ is non-negative for all $x\in\mathbb R$ so $|g| = g$ meaning $|g|$ is also discontiuous. We can say that $f$ being discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$ doesn't imply that $|f|$ is continuous in $[0,1]$.

No I want to say that you have defined a function on your own but is it valid for all other functions which are discontinuous at every point in the interval [0,1] its modulus is satisfying it

No. If you modify the function I used as an example such that $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin \mathbb Q$ then $|f|$ is not continuous.

No, there exists functions that are nowhere continuous on $[0,1]$, and such that $|f|$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$ (the functions that satisfy your statement are really exceptions).
Let me give you an example of function that satisfies your statement, and another one that does not.
The function defined by
$$f(x)=2\times\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb Q}(x)-1=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb Q}(x)-\mathbb{1}_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}(x)$$
satisfies this property: $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x)=-1$ if $x$ is irrational. In any case $|f(x)|=1$. So it satisfies your statement. On the other hand, $g(x):=\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$ is continuous nowhere, and its modulus is $|g|=g$ (because $g\geqslant 0$). So it is also discontinuous everywhere.

You're right PierreCarre, thanks for the advice!
